# remove rows that contain zeros from cells array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cells

I have a cell array resulted from a certain code as follows:

```
m = 

    [         0]    'GO:0008150'
    'GO:0008150'    'GO:0016740'
    'GO:0016740'    'GO:0016787'
    'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006810'
    'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006412'
    'GO:0016740'    'GO:0004672'
    'GO:0016740'    'GO:0016779'
    'GO:0016787'    'GO:0004386'
    'GO:0016787'    'GO:0003774'
    'GO:0016787'    'GO:0016298'
    'GO:0006810'    'GO:0016192'
    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0005215'
    'GO:0004672'    'GO:0030533'
    [         0]    'GO:0008150'
    [         0]    'GO:0016740'
    'GO:0008150'    'GO:0016787'
    'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006810'
    'GO:0006810'    'GO:0006412'
    [         0]    'GO:0004672'
    [         0]    'GO:0016779'
    [         0]    'GO:0004386'
    'GO:0016192'    'GO:0003774'
    [         0]    'GO:0016298'
    [         0]    'GO:0016192'
    'GO:0006810'    'GO:0005215'
    'GO:0005215'    'GO:0030533'
```

I need to remove the rows which contains zero (for example: row one should be deleted because we have a zero in the first column).
so how can I create an array from this array that doesn't contain zeros?

Comment: From your example, and as @Rody Oldenhuis implicitly highlights, this is better suited as finding `char` vs. `double` instead of a zero vs. non-zero)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a pretty one-liner:

```
m(any(cellfun(@(x)x(1)==0, m),2), :) = []
```

Alternatively:

```
m(any(~cellfun(@ischar, m),2), :) = []
```

which is a tad faster.

If you can be certain that only the first column will ever contain a zero, use

```
m = m(cellfun(@ischar, m(:,1)),:)
```

and, finally, you can use

```
m = m(cellfun('isclass', m(:,1), 'char'),:)
```

which looks "old", but actually has greater performance.

Testing these one thousand times on your example array, gives

```
Elapsed time is 1.382801 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.138519 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.075245 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.014674 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  zerosLocation = cellfun(@(x)isEqual(x, 0 ) , m);
  zeroRows = any(zerosLocation,2);
  m(zeroRows,:) = [];
```